# Why PDF file from InDesign shows different dimensions after export?

Tags: adobe-indesign, pdf, export, print-production, adobe-acrobat

The size shown in inches in PDF is significantly different from the InDesign settings in mm. I am worried there are some scaling settings that I missed. I didn't set anything specific though. Exported as PDF for print with bleeds.

Hovering at the bottom left in Acrobat" shows same size as "Properties->Description" and same as "Print Production->Preflight->Page Information" for PDF:
[image]

And here is InDesign Document Setup of the file before export:
[image]

asap

Comment: Yeah, that looks strange. The PDF seems to be 62 x 172 mm. And it doesn't seem to have bleed included as all the boxes are the same size. Please try to use *Page Tool* in InDesign to check the page size of the individual pages. If you have changed them after creating the document, *Document Setup* might not work as intended. AFAIK there is no way to scale a PDF on export in InDesign.

Comment: I can't work out how 800mm translated to 24.409 of *something* -- it's not inches, centimeters, meters, yards, feet...

Comment: It's not even the same aspect ratio so it's not just scaled.